# C console - separating different values

Tags: c, console

I'm new to programming and am trying different activities online to get a grasp for it.
I'm having an issue with a particular problem, I want to make a program where the user enters a value and it prints a particular string.
For example, when the user enters 0, it will print the string 'black', entering 1 will print the string 'brown' as seen in the below image:

[image]

My problem is that I want the user to enter a value such as 012 and it would print "black, brown, red" with spaces. I've made a start by doing the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int colours(int t){
    if(t == 0){
        printf("black");
    }
    else if(t == 1) {
        printf("brown");
    }
    else if (t == 2) {
        printf("red");
    }
    else if(t == 3) {
        printf("orange");
    }
     else if(t == 4) {
        printf("yellow");
    }
     else{
        printf("incorrect colour number");
     }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("colour code"", colours(n));
    return 0;
}
```

How can I print multiple colours at once? I'm not asking for code I just need a hint atleast to what to use, I'm not sure if using IF statements is correct for this problem?

Comment: ***How can I print multiple colours at once*** .... can you explain a little bit more what do you want in the input and the expected output...???

Comment: First learn about the `switch` statement. Then learn about loops. And finally read the input as a string, and get the digits one by one from the string in your loop.

Comment: Your `colors` function is more or less OK (even if it can be simplified), but you should name it `PrintColor` which reflects what it is actually doing. If you want print seversal colors as you describe in your question, you must decompose "012" into the values 0, 1 and 2 and call the `PrintColor` function for each of the values.

Comment: Thanks for that, only question I have is how would I 'decompose' the input? (012)

Comment: @fark You'll find the answer by googling.

Comment: `int colours(int t)` → `void colours(int t)`, Change all `printf` in `colours` function to `puts`, `printf("colour code"", colours(n));` → `puts("Colour code:"); while(n > 0) { colours(n % 10); n = n  / 10; }`(Note: this will print everything in reverse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "decompose" the user input, you could try to receive it as a string, a table of characters.

```
char* input = ( char* ) malloc( sizeof( char ) * maxlength + 1 ); // allocate a char table to store user input, maxlength being the maximum length you expect.
scanf("%s", input);
```

Note 1: you have to add 1 to the maximum length you expect to receive from the user input because scanf will need one more `char` to add the character `\0` to terminate the string.
Note 2: The `\0` character is also known as the `NULL-terminator`.

Then you go through the string like:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < strlen( input ) ; i++ )
{
     colours( input[ i ] );
}
```

Note 1: you have to `#include <string.h>` to use `strlen`.
Note 2: you may have to cast your char into an int to pass it to `colours`, using : `colours( ( int ) input[ i ] );`.
Note 3: Casting a `char` into an `int` gives you the char's ASCII value.

And use the [ASCII code](http://www.ascii-code.com/) (look for numbers) of each `char` to identify and print them. Hence, you can test it using one of the two following:

```
void colours( int t )  // as mentioned in the comments, you do not have to return something.
{
    switch( t ) 
    {
        case 49: // ASCII code of 1
            printf("brown\n");
            break;

        // ... other cases

        default:  // Don't forget the default statement
            printf("incorrect colour number\n");
            break;
    }
}
```

or:

```
switch( t - (int) '0' ) // (ASCII code of t - ASCII code of '0') gives you the number given by the user, as an int
{
    case 1: // 
        printf("brown\n");
        break;

    // ... other cases

    default:
        printf("incorrect colour number\n");
        break;
}
```

As others said in the comments, it is best practice to use a switch case statement when you have to do more than 2 consecutive `else if`.

Finally, don't forget to free the memory you have manually allocated, so you don't have a memory leak:

```
free( input );
```

Comment: Absolute legend, learnt so much from doing this thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would advise you to declare your "colours" function as a type void, as it does not need to return anything (`void colours(int t){`).

*This is the way I would approach this problem:*

Initialize an array which will store a string from a user input (*eg. 123*). Then pass the array to a function (*google this, as it is not as simple as passing an integer*). And then make a loop which will loop through the array until it reaches the end of it and will print a given colour for each pass. (eg. `array[0]` is 1, so print *brown*, `array[1]` is 2, so print *red*, `array[2]` is 3, so print *orange*).